# I want to use scanf to store values in a 2D array in C language. But it doesn't store it like how i want it to

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int matrix[x][y];

    printf("no. of rows \n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("no. of columns \n");
    scanf("%d",&y);

    printf("co-efficient of matrix \n");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < y ; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
            };
        };
    for(int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < y ; j++)
                {
                    printf("%d",matrix[i][j]);
                };
            printf("\n");
        };
        printf("%d",matrix[0][0]);
}
```

Output looks like this.

I input the values:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

but then the in the output is:

```
4 5 6 4 5 6
```

Comment: move it to where? from what I understand, it should be above or it will create more problem.

Comment: A 0-length VLA is undefined behavior...

Comment: `int matrix[x][y];` - `x` and `y` are 0. So this is `matrix[0][0]`.

Comment: @user3121023 You can't declare arrays like that with non const integers. They have to be allocated dynamically.

Comment: @user3121023 It's an extension in C and not standard.

Comment: @user3121023, moving int matrix[x][y]; below scanf("%d",%y); fixed it. thanks you.

Comment: @user3121023 Please make an answer which explains the use of the non-standard VLA extension and how the shown code causes the shown output.

Comment: @Nina: Extensions are the defining of behavior not fully defined by the C standard. Variable length arrays are optional in the current C standard, but they are part of the standard and hence are standard, not an extension.

Answer (score 2):

moving

```c
int matrix[x][y];
```

below

```c
scanf("%d",&y);
```

have fixed the issue. My array had [0][0] dimensions as I was declaring the array right after declaring `x` and `y` which were initialized with 0 value. Hence declaring the array after getting the values of `x` and `y` fixed the problem.

Comment: When you are framing an answer/question, there are instructions on the right hand side on how to format it. Would be helpful to the readers, consider giving it a look.

Comment: @Mihir sorry, i'll be mindful of that in the future.

Comment: How do you expect to allocate a x*y sized matrix when x and y haven't been given their values yet?

Comment: The problem is that the dimensions of the array are determined when program execution reaches the `int matrix[x][y];` declaration. At that time, `x` and `y` are zero (which is improper for defining the size of an array). When `x` and `y` are changed by the later `scanf` calls, that does not change the size of `matrix`. To create `matrix` with dimensions determined by the numbers read from input, you must put the definition of `matrix` after the numbers have been read from input.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer malloc to allocate memory.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    printf("no. of rows \n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("no. of columns \n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    int **matrix= (int **)malloc(sizeof(int)*x*y);
    printf("co-efficient of matrix \n");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < y ; j++)
            {
                scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
            };
        };
    for(int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < y ; j++)
                {
                    printf("%d",matrix[i][j]);
                };
            printf("\n");
        };
        printf("%d",matrix[0][0]);
     free(matrix);
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    printf("no. of columns \n");    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("no. of rows    \n");    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf("co-efficient of matrix \n");


    int* p = (int*)malloc(x * y * sizeof(int));
    //memset(p,0 , x*y*sizeof(int));

    int **matrix=(int**)malloc(y*sizeof(int*));

    for (int a = 0; a < y; a++)
    { 
        matrix[a] = p + a * x;  //matrix[a]=&p[a*x]
    }




    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        scanf("%d", &matrix[j][i]);

    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            printf("%d", matrix[j][i]);

        printf("\n");
    }

    free(matrix);
    free(p);
}
```